# How to debug js files in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

In the sources/debugger tab, I cannot see the js files which are used by the website, but I can see them in Network tab.
Is it because they are loaded via Ajax request instead of being loaded via script tag?
How can I debug those js files?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how they're being compiled (if they are) and served. How are you building and serving your code? **Edit:** Noticed your detail about AJAX request, is the response cached?

Comment: `Is it because they are loaded via Ajax` - can you show how they are loaded, i.e. the code that loads the script

Comment: $.ajax({type:"get",url:scriptPath}); How can js loaded by ajax be debugged(e.g. add breakpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** files can be debugged in **Chrome** Browser the same way you debug **HTML/CSS** files i.e using **Chrome Developer Tools** which can be launched via following shortcuts as per the **OS** you use.

### For Windows and Linux distros:

[image: Dev Tools]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> ➡ Opens Developer Tools

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> ➡ Opens Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ➡ Toggles Inspect Element mode.

### For Mac OS:

[image: Mac Snapshot]

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> ➡ Opens Developer Tools

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> ➡ Opens Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ➡ Toggles Inspect Element mode.

### Using Javascript Profiler:

If you want to get more detailed information about exactly which JavaScript functions were called and how long each took or other runtime script analysis of your script then Chrome offers other additional tools.

[image: Js Profiler]

[Keyboard Shortcuts Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)

[Source: Chrome DevTools Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)